# So we migrated data from an .mdb to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

...which is really easy with Management Studio. Except:

- Datatype "Autonumber" was converted to int and needed manual Identity Specification in Studio (data is well kept)
- Datatype "Yes/No" was converted to bit and needed manual setting of a default value

Then we wanted to use the existing forms, so just link to the new tables, keep the table name and done. Except...

It seems that when adding a new record using the Access tables, the Form has immediately the auto generated primary key for the record, while using SQL, only after the record is saved.

On Normal forms a Me.Refresh in the load event does the trick but in a Continuous Form the same trick fails (gets marked as #Deleted).

Scenario:

- OBDC connected SQL Server table
- While adding record in continuous form
- Click a button event that needs the SQL generated primary key

How to save the record **and** get the generated primary key without getting the #Deleted?

Disclaimer: In my opinion Access is amazing to create functional forms really fast. Development speed is the key, so a quick "hack" is ok, for formal robust solutions access is not the choice.

Comment: Also, use the tool for the purpose: [SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access (AccessToSQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/access/sql-server-migration-assistant-for-access-accesstosql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: At the end, a Me.Refresh on the continuous form button event was kept. Maintained a #Deleted behavior when a single space had been typed but worked in every other case... that was enough. Actually if anything was typed or if a space was typed and then deleted it would work well. Reasons for this were not discovered.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Use `Me.Recordset.Requery` instead of `Me.Refresh`
2. Use `dbSeeChanges` option when open recordsets to see new ID after call `rst.AddNew`

Answer (score 0):

Access autonumbers are reserved/assigned upfront, whereas Identity numbers in SqlServer are generated when the record is saved to the table. If you want to see the Identity number upfront when adding a new record you can save the record and then reopen it to continue entering the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Sql Migration Assistant for Access (SSMA), then your PK and auto numbers would move up to sql server. So will your relationships etc. So, you would not need to manually "mess" with the tables after a migration. For a few tables, then SQL studio to import is ok, but for a complex application, then far too much work is required.

First up:
It is not AT ALL CLEAR why some auto number that appears after you save, or before matters? You have to explain why this is causing an issue - it should not.

For EVERY table, you want:
A defined PK - usually auto number
A TIMESTAMP column (this is NOT to be confused with a date/time column).

If you use the SSMA to migrate, it gives a option to create a PK if one does not exist, and also add the all important "timestamp". This is done automatic.

The end result of above, is your "deleted" issues will disappear and go away. The ONLY case in which you might need the autonumber before a record save is some special code that say needs to run some code or create a child record.

So:
All this messing around, creating PK's, and attempting to re-query forms IS NOT required after a migration. If you having to mess around this much? Then you done your data migration wrong. All of the forms should JUST WORK after a migration. The VERY few exceptions is as noted the wee tiny bit of code in a VERY few places that needed the PK id before a reocrd save. In VERY large applications, I tend to find maybe 2-3 locations were this is a issue.

In most cases, you can check for the ID, and go:

```
if isnull(me!id) = True then
   me.Dirty = False   ' force record save - gen autonumber
End If
' code here to use autonumber pk.
```

So there should be no need to re-query or mess with that sub form. Ensure that a PK exists, and ensure that a timesamp column exists. Once you do that, then re-link the tables. Your forms will work as before and work without code changes, or all this dancing around to re-query. If you having to make such changes, then your table(s) are missing that all important PK, or missing that timestamp column. 
As noted, the SSMAA assistant will do this work for you, and MORE important also allow you to up-load (migrate) your related data intact.

If you don't follow above?
Then you will wind up spending days hacking around your code and forms when ZERO WORK was required here.

Comment: The migration was done using the SSMS of the server in cause. Which was a SQL 2012 I believe. The migration did not return any errors and the application ran, so it was initially assumed as OK. When the PK errors were found it was easier to just correct them manually. From your information, I would believe a newer and specific tool will not have the same issues. So from the experience that will be highly advisable.

Comment: not a huge deal. The more tables and relationships, then the more my tip and suggestion is of value. Try adding the timestamp  column and then re-link that offending table - it should get rid of the "deleted" errors.